# Save - retrieve image database hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to save the picture of each employee in my application next to his / her profile, then retrieve this picture whenever any user open this employee profile, so I have made the following classes:

```
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Long id;
.
//many other fields goes here...
.
@OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private EmployeePicture employeepicture;    
}

public class EmployeePicture {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="EMPPIC_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_PIC")
@Lob
private Blob employeePicture;
}
```

then I created the following DAO class, of course in addition to the EmployeeDAO class which I already have...

```
@Repository
public class EmployeePictureDAO implements IEmployeePictureDAO {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionfactory;

public void saveEmployeePicture(EmployeePicture employeepicture) {
sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().save(employeepicture);
}
public void updateEmployeePicture(EmployeePicture employeepicture) {
sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().update(employeepicture);
}
public void deleteEmployeePicture(EmployeePicture employeepicture) {
sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().delete(employeepicture);
}
public EmployeePicture getEmployeePictureByPK(Long id) {        
return (EmployeePicture)sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().get(EmployeePicture.class,id);
}
}
```

As of service layer classes, I only have the EmployeeService class which I believe shall call both the EmployeeDAO and EmployeePictureDAO methods since both the data and picture will be saved/ updated and deleted in the same time. But unfortunatlly I can't figure out / find (after searching the web) how to Save / retrieve the image from / to the JSP. So can someone please help me by giving me a sample code on how to save / retrieve the employee image inside the Service/ Controller classes and the JSP?

Thanksf or your time

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you display an image in HTML:

```
<img src="the-url-of-the-image" />
```

When the browser sees this `<img>` tag in the HTML page, it sends another HTTP request to the URL referenced in the tag, and the server sends back a response containing the bytes of the image, and a content-type header telling the browser what kind of image it is (`image/jpg`, `image/png`, etc.).

You normally don't have anything to do when the image is a static file, because the web server does all that for you: it deduces the content type from the file extension, reads the file, and sends its data in the response.

In your case, since the image is in the database, you'll have to do that by yourself, by writing a servlet or a Spring MVC controller which gets the image from the database, and sends it back to the HTTP response, with the appropriate conent-type header set.

So, the view generated for the employee profile page will contain something like

```
<img src="<c:url value='/employeePicture">
              <c:param name='employeeId' value='${employee.id}'/>
          </c:url>" />
```

And you'll have a controller mapped to `/employeePicture`, that will load the employee picture from the database, set the response content-type header, and send back the bytes of the image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, as I mentioned in my question I am pretty stuck with building code for controller that will save the image to database and re-load it to be ready to be displayed in <img>. I have searched the web for any sample but couldn't find any so if you can please provide me with example or even a link to an example that will be great. Thanks

Comment: I explained you how to display an image stored in the database. To upload it, read the Spring documentation: it has a section, with examples, explaining how to handle file uploads: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart

Answer (score 0):

We have a little different strategy - we store only images path, but such approach may help you:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/images/{imageId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="image/*")
public void getImage(@PathVariable Long imageId, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ArticleImage requestedImage = articleImageService.findOne(imageId);
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(requestedImage.getPath()); // Make "in" object creation from Blob here (instead of loading resource as stream)
    if (in != null) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }else {
        logger.error("Missing requested image " + requestedImage);
    }
}
```

On view we have:

```
<img src="${home}/images/${article.id}" />
```

So browser makes GET request with url "/images/{id}" and render obtained image.

Hope it helps

Comment: User518469 can you please provide me with sample code or even a link to an online example of how you can 'save' the image in the Controller and Service classes? Problem is that I have no idea how to make the user select image from his/ her drive, then upload it to our server either to be saved as Blob or as a URL to the image path. thanks in advance

Comment: First make your form with correct enctype: <form action=".." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">. Second - create controller method with file in parameters: public String upload(@RequestParam MultipartFile imageFile, ..). Third - write image to File or to DB. Use imageFile.getBytes() method to create inputStream from imageFile

Comment: You can store images: 1) At file system 2) In DB 3) Use special cloud services (like dropbox or cloudinary). Which method to use depends on your situation and your preferences

Comment: Tutorial: http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-specific-location/

Answer (score 0):

To upload the image you can use [Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085511/uploading-images-to-server-in-spring-mvc-and-storing-reference-in-mysql-database/14088291#14088291) is a sample code (instead of saving to the file system, you can save it in your DB). You can find lot of examples on web for file upload.

For retrieval, I would suggest using a servlet dedicated to display images. Here is an example

```
@WebServlet("/image/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Get requested image by path info.
    String requestedImage = request.getParameter("value");
    // Check if file name is actually supplied to the request URI.
    if (requestedImage == null) {
        // Do your thing if the image is not supplied to the request URI.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image,
        // or just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    File image = //retrieve your image from the DB with the id(variable requestedImage);

    // Check if file actually exists.
    if (!image.exists()) {
        // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image,
        // or just ignore it.
        image = new File(imageDir, Constants.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
        if (!image.exists()){
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(image, "rw");
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    f.read(b);
    f.close();
    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    response.getOutputStream().write(b);
}
```

}

And now retrieve the image in your jsp

```
<img src="<c:url value="/image/?value=${id}"/>"/>
```